# Реализация хештегов по аналогии с вк и твиттером

Tags: jquery, html

Прошу прощения за навязчивость с хеш тегами, но хотелось бы узнать как правильно сделать. Добавляем форму добавления коммента:

```
<div id="message_{id}">форма</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).find('div[id*="message_"]').each(function () {
            var message = $(this).text();
            message = message.replace(/@(.[^!"#&'*+,.\/;<>?\\`|~]+)/gi, '<a href="/user-$1" target="_blank">$1</a>').replace(/#([A-zА-я0-9_]+)/gi, '<a href="/?go=search&query=%23$1" target="_blank">#$1</a>'); // @login, #tag
            $(this).html(message);
        });
    });
</script>
```

После окончания загрузки страницы, он ищет по всему документу div'ы с id="message_N", N - это id.

Далее, если находит, он сначала ищет в тексте [[@login](/users/5989/login8)](/users/5989/login8) и заменяет его ссылкой вида `<a href="/user-login" target="_blank">login</a>`, а потом ищет #tag и заменяет их ссылкой вида `<a href="/?go=search&query=%23tag" target="_blank">#tag</a>`.

Итак правилен ли этот код реализации хеш тегов по аналогии с вк или твиттером? Этот скрипт не работает, в чем ошибки, подскажите, пожалуйста?

С уважением.

Answer (score 1):

Мои 5 копеек:

```
message = message.replace(/[@|#]\w+/g, function(match) {
    return '<a href="'+((match[0] == '@')?'/user-':'/?go=search&query=')+match.replace(/@/, '')+ '" target="_blank">'+match+'</a>';
});
```